# Pass diff output to a variable

Tags: vim

I'm trying to run a diff between the current buffer and its savefile. Because I want to do some processing on the diff output, I need it in a variable, not a new buffer. I know that one way to do this is with

```
w !diff % - > tmpfile
let myvar = system( cat tmpfile )
```

Is there any more elegant way?

Comment: Sample `vimrc`s include the `:DiffOrig` command. Since it does not answer your question I leave it as a comment, but this is related and might interest you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are able to write the buffer, you could do something like

```
:let @a=system('diff ' . shellescape(expand('%')) . ' ' . shellescape(expand('%')) . '~')
```

to e.g. compare buffer.txt to buffer.txt~ and put the result in *register* `a`

Otherwise, try

```
:let @a=""
:redir @A
:%w !diff - "%~" 
:redir END
```

In my preliminary test, this appears not to work on Win32 GVIM, though. You might have to go through a temporary file to get this working

I realize this all looks close to what you had tried. Hope it helps anyway, perhaps confirming your thoughts

Comment: Never use `'"'.expand('%').'"'` or `"%~"` for quoting, there is `shellescape()` function that serves this purpose. Don’t forget, POSIX allows everything except only NULL in the filenames, including `"` (and newline, but that does not work inside `system()` and I consider this being a vim bug even though it is a documented one).

Comment: Your first version does what I want. Somehow I never considered comparing to the backup.

Comment: @ZyX Finally found the time to incorporate your feedback. Better late than...?

Comment: @sehe You are still forgetting about `:%w !diff - "%~"`. You have to use `shellescape()` also here, but now `shellescape(, 1)`. Note that `:redir` variant only works inside gvim. Based on your answer, even not in any gvim.

Comment: @ZyX I forgot that :! does shell-exec, effectively :} I'll have to find time to update the answer though :( If you find time earlier, feel free :)